# Why is inital /ŋ/ considered hick-ish?

Tags: pronunciation, topolect

There seems to be a habit of dropping /ŋ/ initials in topolects/dialects for fear of seeming like a redneck.

Consider:

- Canto: 屋 nguk1 vs. uk1 [the new ABC Cantonese dictionary only gives the *uk1* even]
- Southwest Mandarin: 欧 ngou1 vs. ou1

Some claim this is 老派 vs. 新派 but from my experience it's been considered 土 vs. 洋.

Why does the /ŋ/ initial give people a hillbilly-type feeling?

Comment: Can you provide a citation for this consideration? And where is this attitude held, Hong Kong, Guangdong, or some other place? Among younger people or older?

Comment: @congusbongus I'll see if I can find anything that backs up my consideration, might be tough, though.

Comment: https://www.zhihu.com/question/23541509 除了老一辈，你是找不到发/ng/音的 -- maybe something like that but slightly off topic really

Comment: There are so many **/ŋ/** initials in our Xi'an dialect, like 我 nge, 安 ngan, 欧 ngou, etc.

Comment: @賈可Jacky is it considered 土?

Comment: Admittedly, some young people's accent is being affected by Mandarin gradually, the syllables like Mandarin, but the tones is still the same as their dialect, but not all syllables, not all people is affected. We don't say they are 土 or 洋, at least, it is very common in our home.

Comment: There are still many /ŋ/ initials in our dialect in the coming tens of yeas.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that there's a tendency to drop initial /ŋ/ in Wu (Shanghainese), but I always ascribed it to the proximity of the word to Mandarin:

> 我 
> Mandarin: wo3 
> Wu: (吾) ngu34
>
> 外 
> Mandarin: wai4 
> Wu: nga53

Whereas it is clearly voiced when it occurs in more language-specific words or single syllables (obviously):

> 硬 
> Mandarin: ying4 
> Wu: ngang53
>
> 五 
> Mandarin: wu3 
> Wu: ng34
>
> 鱼 
> Mandarin: yu2 
> Wu: ng34

Comment: How about any stigma attached to /ŋ/ initials in Wu? Does it sound more "土"?

Comment: I believe it's exactly the opposite: they are very proud people and outside of their home they speak dialect whenever they can as a sign of belonging. They even do it in formal circumstances.